# Query works in Prisma playground but always null from front-end

Tags: reactjs, apollo, prisma

Im using Prisma, Apollo and React. Ive added a picture field to Users which shows up fine in the Prisma playground but in React it always comes back null, but if I query other fields its fine. Im really confused why this isn't working, have I made a syntax error?

datamodel.graphql:

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  picture: String
}
```

schema.graphql:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  picture: String
}

type Query {
  user(id: ID!): User
}
```

My resolver:

```
  async user(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    const { id } = args;
    const result = await ctx.db.query.user({ where: { id } }, info);
    return result;
  },
```

React component:

```
export const USER_QUERY = gql`
  query UserQuery($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      id
      picture
    }
  }
`;

export default compose(
  graphql(USER_QUERY, {
    name: 'USER_QUERY',
    options: props => {
      return {
        variables: {
          userId: 'cjgylfv6y004h0958tx9d8j9v',
        },
      };
    },
  }),
)(UserPic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark.

I see you have fixed user id `cjgylfv6y004h0958tx9d8j9v` in your code. If that user was inserted before deploying your changes to Prisma, it would have a null value for the attribute picture.

Try with a query that lists all your users.